# Confusion regarding finding closed loop transfer function and damping constant from open-loop transfer function

Tags: control, control-system, system, closed-loop, damping-factor

I have second order transfer function $$ G(s) = \frac{1.247}{s^2+9.76s+23.8}$$ G(s) is in the forward path of a unity feedback system.

How do I find the closed loop transfer function and damping constant from this? Now I know that the equation to find the closed loop transfer function is $$TF = \frac{G}{1+G}$$

If I use that here, I get $$TF = \frac{1.247}{s^2+9.76s+25.047}$$ and It is not in the form of a standard second order system which is $$TF = \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\delta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}$$

That is, the numerator in **TF** is not 25.047. So How do I calculate damping ratio in this situation? Can I still take 25.047 as the square of natural frequency and equate that with the coefficient of **s** to find damping ratio?

Comment: $$TF =K \frac{\omega_n^2}{s^2+2\delta\omega_ns+\omega_n^2}$$ this is standard form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [user215805](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/255936/user215805) stated, the standard form is
$$TF=K\frac{\omega^2_n}{s^2+2\delta\omega_ns+\omega^2_n}$$
And you have
$$TF=\frac{1.247}{s^2+9.76s+25.047}$$
This means that in your case $$\omega^2_n=25.047$$
Which you already know, but notice that from the standard form you can deduce that
$$K\omega^2_n=1.247$$
And simply
$$K=\frac{1.247}{\omega^2_n}=\frac{1.247}{25.047}≈0.05$$
So now you have
$$TF=0.05\frac{25.047}{s^2+9.76s+25.047}$$
Similarly you can deduce that
$$2\delta\omega_n=9.76$$
And therefore
$$\delta=\frac{9.76}{2\omega_n}≈0.975$$
And so you have reached the standard form
$$TF=0.05\frac{25.047}{s^2+2(0.975)\sqrt{25.047}s+25.047}$$